# How to update the d3js - graph data alone without re-appending `svg` element

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

How to update the data of the existing graph in `d3.js`. i am trying but i am getting error.

Actually, this is my requirement for angular.  i have a single directive withing that, i would like to update data by sending different scenario of function call.

here is my try :

```
$(function(){

  var data = [30, 70];
  var phrase = "Graphics";
  var datas = [
      [40,60],
      [85,15],
      [20,80]
    ]

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                    .sort(null)
                    .value(function(d) { return d });

  var drawPie = function (array, phrase, element, num) {

                var width = element.width(), height = element.height(),
                radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2, data = array;


                if(!data.length) return;

                var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(data)
                    .range(["#ffff00", "#1ebfc5"]);

                var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
                    .innerRadius(radius - 5);


                var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .attr("id", function(d,i) {return 'pie'+num;})
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


                 var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                      .data(pie(data))
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "arc");

                  g.append("path")
                      .attr("d", arc)
                      .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(d.data); });

                 g.append("text")
                     .text(data[0]+'%')
                     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + radius / 4 + ")")
                     .attr("class", "designVal")
                     .style("text-anchor", "middle")


            }

    drawPie( data, phrase, $('#first'), 1); 
    drawPie( data, phrase, $('#second'), 2);

    $('button').on('click', function() {

      var index = $(this).index();
      var array = datas[index]; //getting different array;
      d3.select('#pie2').selectAll("path").data(pie(array));

    })

});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/thMNCPGn1gGYVly9k6zY?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the new properties values (from the newly loaded data) using `.attr`. Here the attributes affected are path (d) and text - you just need to call them again. The path needs `arc` - which you can construct as before (using #second).

```
    ...
    var element = $('#second')
    var width = element.width(), height = element.height()
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2      
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(radius - 5);

    d3.select('#pie2').selectAll("path").data(pie(array)).attr("d", arc);
    d3.select('#pie2').selectAll("text").text(array[0]+'%');
})
```

---

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/1HTW9OQV9Ow93p1bLcDT?p=preview